# Convert Hindi text to Escaped Unicode character with php

Tags: php, unicode, unicode-escapes

I want to convert hindi / Devanagari text for example "आए थे पर्यटक, खुद ही बह ग" into Unicode escaped characters like "\u0906\u090f \u0925\u0947 \u092a\u0930\u094d\u092f\u091f\u0915, \u0916\u0941\u0926 \u0939\u0940 \u092c\u0939 \u0917".

I am developing a hindi website and i have seen most of sites are using Escaped Unicode sequence inside their meta tags and schema.org.
So i decided to give it a try.

i can see Hindi AKA Devanagari letters with their Escaped Unicode sequence at http://www.endmemo.com/unicode/devanagari.php

and i have also seen a tool which works the same https://www.mobilefish.com/services/unicode_escape_sequence_converter/unicode_escape_sequence_converter.php

but i cannot find any way to convert these Devanagari letters into Escaped Unicode sequence via php.

I have tried few things but nothing is working and i am not getting much help from google because all articles / forums are talking to decoding unicode escape sequence to unicode but none of them is taking about encoding..

```
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' ); 


function encode2($str) {
    $str = mb_convert_encoding($str , 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8');
    $t = unpack("N*", $str);
    $t = array_map(function($n) { return "&#$n;"; }, $t);
    return implode("", $t);
}

$message = "आए थे पर्यटक, खुद ही बह गए";
$message_convert = encode2($message); 
echo $message_convert;

echo "fdfdfdfdfdfdfd<br/>";


echo mb_convert_encoding($message, "HTML-ENTITIES", "auto");
```

I want this "आए थे पर्यटक, खुद ही बह ग" to "\u0906\u090f \u0925\u0947 \u092a\u0930\u094d\u092f\u091f\u0915, \u0916\u0941\u0926 \u0939\u0940 \u092c\u0939 \u0917"

Please help!

Comment: Can't you just use ```json_encode($message)``` ? This should give back ```string(123) ""\u0906\u090f \u0925\u0947 \u092a\u0930\u094d\u092f\u091f\u0915, \u0916\u0941\u0926 \u0939\u0940 \u092c\u0939 \u0917\u090f""
```

Comment: Ohh! It's working

Answer (score 1):

as suggest by @paskl i tried:

```
$message = "आए थे पर्यटक, खुद ही बह गए";
$unicode = json_encode($message)

echo $unicode;
```

And i got ""\u0906\u090f \u0925\u0947 \u092a\u0930\u094d\u092f\u091f\u0915, \u0916\u0941\u0926 \u0939\u0940 \u092c\u0939 \u0917\u090f""

I hope it will help others who want to convert devanagari/hindi letters into Escaped Unicode sequence with php on their website.

Thanks to @paskl

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're looking to transmit this data as JSON I wouldn't really recommend using `json_encode()` as it will wrap your output in literal double quotes that you'd need to strip back off. However there's not an easy way to encode unicode escapes in PHP in a way that is memory-efficient.

That said, here is the not-easy code:

```
// PHP < 7.2
// https://github.com/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/blob/master/Mbstring.php#L708-L730
if( ! function_exists("mb_ord") ) {
    function mb_ord($s) {
        if (1 === \strlen($s)) {
            return \ord($s);
        }
        $code = ($s = unpack('C*', substr($s, 0, 4))) ? $s[1] : 0;
        if (0xF0 <= $code) {
            return (($code - 0xF0) << 18) + (($s[2] - 0x80) << 12) + (($s[3] - 0x80) << 6) + $s[4] - 0x80;
        }
        if (0xE0 <= $code) {
            return (($code - 0xE0) << 12) + (($s[2] - 0x80) << 6) + $s[3] - 0x80;
        }
        if (0xC0 <= $code) {
            return (($code - 0xC0) << 6) + $s[2] - 0x80;
        }
        return $code;
    }
}

function ord2seqlen($ord) {
    if($ord < 128){
        return 1;
    } else if($ord < 224) {
        return 2;
    } else if($ord < 240) {
        return 3;
    } else if($ord < 248) {
        return 4;
    } else {
        throw new \Exception("No support for 5 or 6 byte sequences.");
    }
}

function utf8_seq_iter($input) {
    for($i=0,$c=strlen($input); $i<$c; ) {
        $bytes = ord2seqlen(ord($input[$i]));
        yield substr($input, $i, $bytes);
        $i += $bytes;
    }
}

function escape_codepoint($codepoint, $skip_low=true) {
    $ord = mb_ord($codepoint);
    if( $skip_low && $ord < 128 ) {
        return $codepoint;
    } else {
        return sprintf("\\u%04x", $ord);
    }
}

$input = "आए थे पर्यटक, खुद ही बह गए";
$output = '';

foreach( utf8_seq_iter($input) as $codepoint ) {
    $output .= escape_codepoint($codepoint);
}

var_dump($output);
```

Output:

```
string(121) "\u0906\u090f \u0925\u0947 \u092a\u0930\u094d\u092f\u091f\u0915, \u0916\u0941\u0926 \u0939\u0940 \u092c\u0939 \u0917\u090f"
```

---

**Edit:** I've turned this into a small composer package available here:

https://packagist.org/packages/wrossmann/utf8_escape